# Get value of unlimited textfield in array

Tags: arrays, function, api, reactjs

How to get value from unlimited `input[type="text]` in array

**Children.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Children extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div id={"children-"+this.props.number}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" className="fullWidth"/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Age" className="fullWidth"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

**Parent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Children from './Children.js'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

export default class NewProduct extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            numOfChildren: 0,
        }
    }

    onAddChildren () {
        this.setState({
            numOfChildren: this.state.numOfChildren + 1
        });
    }

    render() {
        const children = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numOfChildren; i += 1) {
            children.push(<Children 
                                number={i} 
                                key={i} 
                            />);
        }

        return (
            <div className="form">
                <div className="tab-content">
                    {children}
                    <RaisedButton
                        label="Add Children"
                        onTouchTap={this.onAddChildren.bind(this)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The results must be like this : 
value-A-1 : "value A 1", value-B-1 : "value B 1"
value-A-2 : "value A 2", value-B-2 : "value B 2"
value-A-3 : "value A 3", value-B-3 : "value B 3"

So the array will be like this:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "value-A" : "value A 1",
        "value-B" : "value B 1"
    }
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "value-A" : "value A 2",
        "value-B" : "value B 2"
    }
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "value-A" : "value A 3",
        "value-B" : "value B 3"
    }
]
```

I'm really appreciate if you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to take all the values on your input fields after you click on a button?

Comment: @MaduraPradeep yes, i want take all the values of input fields after click on a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with this approach:

Children.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Children extends Component {    
    render() {
        return(
            <div id={"children-"+this.props.number}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" className="fullWidth" onChange={({target: {value}}) => this.props.onNameChange(value)}/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Age" className="fullWidth" onChange={({target: {value}}) => this.props.onAgeChange(value)}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

Children.defaultProps = {
    onNameChange: () => null,
    onValueChange: () => null,
}
```

Parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Children from './Children.js'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

export default class NewProduct extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            numOfChildren: 0,
        }
        this.result = [];
    }

    onAddChildren () {
        this.setState({
            numOfChildren: this.state.numOfChildren + 1
        });
    }

    render() {
        const children = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numOfChildren; i += 1) {
            this.result[i] = {name: '', age: '', id: i + 1);
            const index = i;
            children.push(<Children 
                                number={i}
                                key={i}
                                onNameChange={value => this.result[index].name = value}
                                onAgeChange={value => this.result[index].name = value}
                            />);
        }

        return (
            <div className="form">
                <div className="tab-content">
                    {children}
                    <RaisedButton
                        label="Add Children"
                        onTouchTap={this.onAddChildren.bind(this)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

this.result will store something like the array you described.

I didn't check the above code but it should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to state for hold your input results in the constructor

```
this.state = {
 numOfChildren: 0,
 data:[]
}
```

Add an onChange function to Parent class which push the results to the state

```
onChange(index,key,value){
 let data=this.state.data;
 data[index][key]=value;
 this.setState({data:data});
}
```

Pass onChange as a callback to the Child

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numOfChildren; i += 1) {
     children.push(<Children onChange={this.onChange}
                                number={i} 
                                key={i} 
                            />);
}
```

In Children call onChange callback with the number and the value name and value

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Children extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div id={"children-"+this.props.number}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" className="fullWidth" onChange={(e)=>this.props.onChange(this.props.number,"value-A",e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Age" className="fullWidth" onChange={(e)=>this.props.onChange(this.props.number,"value-B",e.target.value)}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: it seem to have an error when submit:
`Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at Object.onChange [as onChange]`

Comment: Did you bind onChange into current context in the constructor or in the function?

Eg: 
<Children onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                                number={i} 
                                key={i} 
                            />